# Why do I get "no such method exception"?

Tags: java

This is my code and it seems to be fine but when I compile the program I get No Such method exception

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Invoked {

 public static String celebname = "Sometext" ;
 public static  String urladdress = "someurl
public static void main(String args[])  {

Main.setpagesource(celebname);
Main.seturl(urladdress);

    try {
        Main.Calculate();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

And the second class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {


public static String address;
public static String celebfilename;
public static String pagesource;

public static void Calculate() throws MalformedURLException {

      URL url1 = new URL(address) ;
    URLConnection connection1 = null;
    try {
        connection1 = url1.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection1.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Documents\\"+"pagesource"+".txt";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    String textreader;
    try {
        while ((textreader = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bw.write(textreader);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }


 }

 public static void seturl(String addressname){

   address = addressname;
}

 public static void settextfilename(String celebfilename1){
   celebfilename = celebfilename1;
}


 public static void setpagesource(String pagesourcename){
    pagesource = pagesourcename;
 }
 }
```

I get the following exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7541 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\untitled6\out\production\untitled6;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Do I really have asked such an out of context question that I have gotten those too many negative points?

Comment: Perhaps you've configured your IDE to run the `Main` class, instead of the `Invoked` class which does have a main() method.

Comment: `public static  String urladdress = "someurl` does not look like a compilable statement, is this a typo?

Comment: Information has been removed and url has been replaced.

Answer (score 5):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

This error means your compiler didn't find your main class.
When you have this kind of error, most of the time it meanss you moved your main class from a file to another without changing your run configuration.

In Intellij, the first time you run your program you right-click on a file containing a "public static main(String[] args)" method. The next time you click on "run" it use the same file and look for a main class. If you moved your main class, the IDE can't guess it and therefore throw you this exception.

So just rerun your code with right-click on the "Invoyed" class, then "run Invoked.main()".
Note that the class you are running is displayed left of the green run arrow.

As a general tip, if you got an error first check you are running the correct class and not some old main class.