# Java compiler error

Tags: java, exception

I am getting a `Exception` in `Thread` `main`

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.laurens.Main.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
```

Can someone explain where I am going wrong here?

Main

```
   package com.laurens;
   public class Main {
   private player player;

     public Main(com.laurens.player player) {
    this.player = player;
     }

public com.laurens.player getPlayer() {
    return player;
      }

public void setPlayer (int performance, String name) {
    if (performance < 4) {

        boolean injured = true;

    }

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.laurens.Main{" +
            "player=" + player +
            '}';
}
 }
```

player

```
 package com.laurens;

/**
* Created by laurensvanoorschot on 20-01-16.
 */
  public class player {
  private String name;
   private int performance;
  private boolean injured;

public player(int performance, boolean injured, String name) {
    this.injured = injured;
    this.name = name;
    this.performance = performance;
}

public boolean isInjured() {
    return injured;
}

public void setInjured(boolean injured) {
    this.injured = injured;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getPerformance() {
    return performance;
}

public void setPerformance(int performance) {
    this.performance = performance;
    }
   }
```

Comment: where is the main() method ?

Comment: Class Main is the main method, but that shouldn't prevent complier from running the code.

Comment: probably an intellij issue. You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/a/24142199/3215527

Comment: @LaurensVanOorschot, you didn't post the code of your `main()` method, the main where you run your code.

Comment: That's not a compiler error.

Comment: That's all the code I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a method called main, which is what it is looking for to run your program. Notice that when you create a template application for a java console application in intelliJ it has a method:

```
public static void main(string[] args) { 

}
```

That needs to be there for your program to run.

Comment: Thanks, but now the code doesn't do anything. How do I execute the toString method so it read the player object?

Comment: Just call the method i.e toString(), just within the main function. The main function is where the code will be executed.

Comment: Tried it, but getting Error:(5, 9) java: non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Make the methods static, it's pretty much what it says :) You can't call non-static code from a static method (the main method is static)

Comment: But the toString needs to be static else it won't be able to return anything. How do I change it to now static?

Comment: static String toString()

Comment: Thanks, but then I get: Error:(25, 27) java: toString() in com.laurens.Main cannot override toString() in java.lang.Object
  overriding method is static
Error:(27, 29) java: non-static variable player cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I am trying to get the player method from the player class in the string, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Create a separate file for your Player class, and add the functions in there. Then in your main create the player and call the function.

Comment: I have  created two classes in separate files( see code) . The first one is called main and the other is  player. How do I call it to the toString method?

Comment: Your toString function should be within the player using an override